# Delete row from table using button - Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I'm trying the row to be deleted when I click the delete icon in the table using bootstrap table.

My table:

```
<table id="checkDataTable">
    <thead style="color: #31708f; background-color: #d9edf7 ">
        <tr>
            <th data-field="AssetReference">Referans</th>
            <th data-field="Customer">Müsteri</th>
            <th data-field="ReceiverCompanyName">Alici Firma</th>
            <th data-field="Tools" data-formatter="StatuFormatter">Islem</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function StatuFormatter(value, row, index) {

    return "<a onclick='removeAssetEconomyCheckBillOfLadingRow()'><i class='fa fa-trash fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
}

function removeAssetEconomyCheckBillOfLadingRow(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

It's fine until the removeAssetEconomyCheckBillOfLadingRow function.

How can I delete inside this function?

Comment: `onclick='removeAssetEconomyCheckBillOfLadingRow()'` doesn't include passing the `id`, at a *guess* it would be `".. onclick='removeAssetEconomyCheckBillOfLadingRow(" + index + ")'  .."`

Comment: I sent the index value. But it doesn't remove .

Comment: `
function removeAssetEconomyCheckBillOfLadingRow(index) {

    $('#checkDataTable').bootstrapTable('remove', {
        field: 'index',
        values: index
    });

  
}`

Comment: Is the `id` getting sent to `removeAssetEconomyCheckBillOfLadingRow` (as shown via the `alert`)?

Comment: Value comes when I check with Alert.

Comment: Then your issue with `boostrapTable("remove"` is a different question.  Please update the your question with what you actually want answered or ask a new question if there's already a valid answer for getting `id`.  My comment above does not count as an answer to your original question, but the other two might.  I'd go with updating your question (not via a comment) to include more details regarding the "bootstrap table delete" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.deleteRow', function(event) {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="checkDataTable" class="table">
  <thead style="color: #31708f; background-color: #d9edf7 ">
    <tr>
      <th data-field="AssetReference">Referans</th>
      <th data-field="Customer">Müşteri</th>
      <th data-field="ReceiverCompanyName">Alıcı Firma</th>
      <th data-field="Tools" data-formatter="StatuFormatter">İşlem</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tobdy>
    <tr>
      <td>Data1</td>
      <td>Data1</td>
      <td>Data1</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="deleteRow">
                    Delete
                    </button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data2</td>
      <td>Data2</td>
      <td>Data2</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="deleteRow">
                    Delete
                    </button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data3</td>
      <td>Data3</td>
      <td>Data3</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="deleteRow">
                    Delete
                    </button></td>
    </tr>
  </tobdy>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to do it using bootstrap table events.Thank you for answer

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, you need to set id to  to identify the deleting row.

```
<tr id="1"></tr>
```

2. And get tr and remove

```
function removeAssetEconomyCheckBillOfLadingRow(id) {
    $('#checkDataTable').row($('#{{id}}'))).remove().draw();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think there is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: `'#{{id}}'` will be a fixed string as it's in js.  Did you mean to use javascript a template string?